# Android multiple screens design philosophy

Tags: java, android

I know how the calculations are done to make resources for xhdpi and hdpi if we are starting from xxhdpi.
We scale down the image 25% and 33% so as to look the same in all devices.

Now here is my problem . Isn't the fact that an image would look same sized on all devices , is a wrong idea to begin with ?
For example if I have a banner on the top of the screen (xxhdpi like S4,XPERIA) , the SAME SIZED banner would appear on a smaller screen
like Nexus S( hdpi ) or other cellphones in the hdpi lines.

Now the banner looks right on S4 because it was designed for the large screen , but the same banner would look wrong in Nexus , it would look too big .

What part of the android design princples philosophy am I missing ?

Comment: Same sized is a wrong concept per se. You should think of things as properly scaled. To scale well, all objects should relate to each other, and use dp (sp for fonts) - where possible.

Comment: If you are going by what you said, you would have scaled the image down by 33% so the images are different sizes but in relation to the screen, they look fine. No?

Comment: DPI is the dots per inch, not the size of the screen. The same asset will appear roughly the same size in real-world inches on all devices.